# This cobol Grammar doesn't handle --9 picture

Tags: cobol, bnf, javacc, ebnf

I'm using the grammar on this site in my javacc. It works fine apart from some picture statements. For example ----,---,---.99 or --9.

> http://mapage.noos.fr/~bpinon/cobol.jj

It doesn't seem to like more than one dash.

What do I need to change in this to support my picture examples.

I'v messed about with

```
void NumericConstant() :
{}
{
  (<PLUSCHAR>|<MINUSCHAR>)? IntegerConstant() [ <DOTCHAR> IntegerConstant() ]
}
```

but nothing seems to be working. Any help is much appreciated

EDIT:

```
<COBOL_WORD: ((["0"-"9"])+ (<MINUSCHAR>)*)*
    (["0"-"9"])* ["a"-"z"] ( ["a"-"z","0"-"9"] )*
    ( (<MINUSCHAR>)+ (["a"-"z","0"-"9"])+)*
>
```

Is this the regular expression for this whole line:

```
07 STRINGFIELD2 PIC AAAA. ??
```

If I want to accept `05 TEST3 REDEFINES TEST2 PIC X(10).` would I change the regex to be:

> ```
> <COBOL_WORD: ((["0"-"9"])+ (<MINUSCHAR>)*)*
> (<REDEFINES> (["0"-"9"])* ["a"-"z"] ( ["a"-"z","0"-"9"] )*)?
>     (["0"-"9"])* ["a"-"z"] ( ["a"-"z","0"-"9"] )*
>     ( (<MINUSCHAR>)+ (["a"-"z","0"-"9"])+)*
> ```

Thanks a lot for the help so far

Comment: A COBOL_WORD is a single token. `07 STRINGFIELD2 PIC AAAA.` contains multiple tokens, some of which classify as COBOL_WORD (eg. STRINGFIELD2) and some classify differently (eg. PIC and separator period after `AAAA`). REDEFINES is a reserved word and should not parse as a COBOL_WORD. The JavaCC source you referenced already contains a `REDEFINES` rule so you should be using that.

Comment: Thanks @NealB. During my tests when I enter `07 STRINGFIELD2 PIC ----,---,---.99` I do not get a parse error. ie. ParseException not thrown. Why would this be? All it does is not parse that data name and causes everything after that not to parse either yet an exception in not thrown.

Comment: In additional to your Cobol_word answer. Could I not have some sort of picture word (PIC_WORD) that I can use after the PIC symbol. In that I could support the dashes in my example. Also in that javacc a dash isn't used as a separator so it should be able to deal with the picture clause I would have thought. Sorry for all the questions. I find this quite interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you messing around with `NumericConstant()` when you are trying to parse a
COBOL PICTURE string?

According to the JavaCC source you have, a COBOL PICTURE should parse with:

```
void DataPictureClause() :
{}
{
  ( <PICTURE> | <PIC> ) [ <IS> ] PictureString()
}
```

the `--9` bit is a Picture String and should parse with the `PictureString()` function:

```
void PictureString() :
{}
{
    [ PictureCurrency() ]
    ( ( PictureChars() )+ [ <LPARENCHAR> IntegerConstant() <RPARENCHAR> ] )+
    [ PicturePunctuation() ( ( PictureChars() )+ [ <LPARENCHAR> IntegerConstant() <RPARENCHAR> ] )+ ]
}
```

`PictureCurrency()` comes up empty so move on to `PictureChars()`:

```
void PictureChars() :
{}
{
    <INTEGER> | <COBOL_WORD>
}
```

But `COBOL_WORD` does not appear to support many "interesting" valid PICTURE clause definitions:

```
<COBOL_WORD: ((["0"-"9"])+ (<MINUSCHAR>)*)*
    (["0"-"9"])* ["a"-"z"] ( ["a"-"z","0"-"9"] )*
    ( (<MINUSCHAR>)+ (["a"-"z","0"-"9"])+)*
>
```

Parsing COBOL is not easy, in fact it is probably one of the most difficult languages in existance to build a quality parser
for. I can tell you right now that the
JavaCC source you are working from is not going to cut it - except for some very simple and probably
totally artificial COBOL program examples.

**Answer to comment**

COBOL Picture strings tend to mess up the best of parsers. The minus sign you are
having trouble with is only the tip of the iceburg! Picture Strings 
are difficult to
parse through because the period and comma
may be part of a Picture string but serve as separators outside of the string. This means
that *parsers cannot unambiguously classify a period or comma in a context free manner*. They need
to be "aware" of the context in which it is encountered. This may sound trivial but it isn't.

Technically, the separator period and comma must be followed by a space (or end of line). This
little fact could make determining the period/comma role very simple because a Picture String
cannot contain a space. However, many
commercial COBOL compilers are "smart" enough correctly recognize separator periods/commas that 
are not followed by a space. 
Consequently
there are a lot of COBOL programmers that code illegal separator period/commas, which means you 
will probably have to deal with them.

The bottom line is that no matter what you do, those little Picture Strings are going to
haunt you. They will take quite a bit of effort to to deal with.

Just a hint of things to come, how would you parse the following:

```
01 DISP-NBR-1 PIC -99,999.
01 DISP-NBR-2 PIC -99,999..
01 DISP-NBR-3 PIC -99,999, .
01 DISP-NBR-4 PIC -99,999,.
```

The period following `DISP-NBR-1` terminates the Picture string. It is a separator period. The
period following `DISP-NBR-2` is part of the string, the second period is the separator. The comma
following `DISP-NBR-3` is a separator - it is not part of the Picture string. However the comma
following `DISP-NBR-4` is part of the Picture string because it is not followed by a space.

Welcome to COBOL!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was thinking in the MINUSCHAR Token I could use a regualr expression instead of using just "-". Something like ["-"]+ ? Not sure if that would work. What can I do so it works with my example (--9) ?

Comment: Great answer. Seems like it will be challenging. I also wanna try and implement the redefines it doesnt work with the current grammar. For example.  05 TEST3 REDEFINES TEST2 PIC X(10). Would I have to edit the COBOL_WORD Token to achieve this?

Comment: I'v edited my question to explain what I'm looking to do with REDFINES :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to switch the lexer into another mode when I got PICTURE. A COBOL PICTURE string has completely different 'lexics' from the rest of the language, and you must discourage the lever from doing anything with periods, commas, etc, other than accumulate them into the picture string. See NealB's answer for some examples of knowing when to stop picture-scanning.

I have no idea why you want to incorporate the REDEFINES phrase into the word. Just parse it normally in the parser.